# invalid in the HAVING clause

Tags: sql-server

```
Select p.CustomerNumber, p.CustomerName,  sum(CAST(a.CRAmountUSD AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS sumCosts
From Scoring p inner join
      CreditNoteDetail a 
     on p.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber  
where a.SerialNumber = p.SerialNumber --'FJM10696'
Group By p.CustomerNumber, p.CustomerName
having sum(CAST(a.CRAmountUSD AS DECIMAL(10,2))) > CAST(p.Amount AS DECIMAL(10,2))
```

I have problem, is error like this

> Msg 8121, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Column 'Scoring.Amount' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

I want to find a comparison value, the amount of 'CRAmountUSD' in the CreditNoteDetail table is smaller than 'Amount' in the Scoring table based on SerialNumber

Comment: The error is telling you the issue here, `p.Amount` (in your `HAVING`) is neither in an aggregate function, nor in the `GROUP BY`; it needs to be in one or the other. Without **consumable** sample data and expected results, we can't easily tell you which is the correct one.

Comment: Why are you repeating your `ON` clause in the `WHERE` as well? If `p.SerialNumber = a.SerialNumber` is true then, by definition `a.SerialNumber = p.SerialNumber` is true. `a = b` and `b = a` are synonyms.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired output. It's almost impossible to guess what you're trying to do from the code since the code isn't valid SQL.